# Check if current directory is a Git repository

Tags: git

I am writing a series of scripts for Git management in zsh.

How do I check if the current directory is a Git repository? (When I'm not in a Git repo, I don't want to execute a bunch of commands and get a bunch of `fatal: Not a git repository` responses).

Comment: Have you looked at the bash completion file (in contrib/completion/git-completion.bash ) for inspiration? I use the __git_ps1 command as part of my bash prompt. In fact most of it will source within zsh. The __gitdir function is probably the one you want.

Comment: @jabbie: why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: Have you checked functions already in zsh distribution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if directory is under git control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044574/determine-if-directory-is-under-git-control)

Comment: Note: none of the current answers consider the `$GIT_DIR` or `$GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables, or how they interact.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Copied from the bash completion file, the following is a naive way to do it

```
# Copyright (C) 2006,2007 Shawn O. Pearce <spearce@spearce.org>
# Conceptually based on gitcompletion (http://gitweb.hawaga.org.uk/).
# Distributed under the GNU General Public License, version 2.0.

if [ -d .git ]; then
  echo .git;
else
  git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null;
fi;
```

You could either wrap that in a function or use it in a script.

Condensed into a one line condition suitable for *bash* and *zsh*

```
[ -d .git ] && echo .git || git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Why not just use git rev-parse?

Comment: @William Pursell Why fork when you don't need to? Mainly for speed in the trivial case.

Comment: Added a simple `$PWD` so the output path always is absolute (like the `git` command): `([ -d .git ] && echo "$PWD/.git") || (git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null)`

Comment: The answer should be updated to use `git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir`. I personally use `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` before set my PS1.

Comment: @JoelPurra `git rev parse --git-dir` prints just `.git` for me on Git 1.9.1.286.g5172cb3.

Comment: @juliohm `--is-inside-git-dir` will only return true if you are actually inside the **`.git` directory** of a repository. I don't think the OP is looking for that.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, that is why I also mentioned `--is-inside-work-tree`.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: works for me in git 1.9.3 on Mac, but doesn't in 1.9.0 on FreeBSD. Hmm. YMMV, I guess.

Comment: Neither `--is-inside-work-tree` nor `--is-inside-git-dir` will work when you are outside of a git repo.  see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/dWc23LFhWxE

Comment: @fisherwebdev That error is the same output I get from `git rev-parse --git-dir` when outside a git repo. That's why stderr is redirected. The test still works for this purpose.

Comment: This will fail if the git directory is something other than `.git`. For robustness, omit the `[ -d .git ]` and just use `git rev-parse ...`.

Comment: @PeterJohnAcklam you mean, if there is a `.git` directory, but the git repo dir is somewhere else? Technically possible maybe, but ... why would you ever setup something like that?

Comment: This command fails if we have a repository inside a master repository. Not like a submodule but when one repository clones other repositories inside it.

Comment: Beware that this will work as expected ONLY IF you're currently in the repository root. Subdirectories are not supported.

Answer (score 274):

You can use:

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
```

Which will print 'true' to STDOUT if you are in a git repos working tree.

Note that it still returns output to STDERR if you are outside of a git repo (and does not print 'false').

Taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044714/12983

Comment: This is te simplest way to check it out.

Comment: This will still print false for a bare repository that has no working tree

Comment: This does not consider the sub-directory. I need to verify does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` matches with the subfolder I am checking

Comment: The chosen answer didn't even print out anything.  This one worked.

Comment: Can we do something like: `if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then` like `William Pursell`s answer?

Comment: @ScottyBlades In context, I would assume that means the chosen answer reports the result in its exit status and intentionally doesn't print anything, to be more directly/easily usable in shell scripts. Was that not the case?

Comment: I am wondering why not simply run the command "git status" instead of running "git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree"

Answer (score 72):

Use git rev-parse --git-dir

```
if git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  : # This is a valid git repository (but the current working
    # directory may not be the top level.
    # Check the output of the git rev-parse command if you care)
else
  : # this is not a git repository
fi
```

edit:  `git-rev-parse` now (as of 1.7.0) supports `--show-toplevel`, so you could do `if test "$(pwd)" = "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"` to determine if the current directory is the top-level dir.

Comment: [What is `> /dev/null 2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10508843/9157799)

Comment: @MImamPratama The `> /dev/null` redirects stdout to the bit bucket.  The `2>&1` sends stderr to the same place.

Comment: the `--show-toplevel` really solved my issues! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why does `2> /dev/null` not work?

Comment: @ocodo `2> /dev/null` works just fine, but it only redirects stderr.  You could write `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` as well.  Using `2>&1` is just less verbose.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify what I'm saying, the true/false output is on stderr, however when I used `2> /dev/null` it still outputs "true" to the shell.

Comment: @ocodo What "true/false output"?  `git rev-parse --git-dir` prints the relative path of the git directory to stdout.

Comment: this is for `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree`  not `-git-dir`.

Comment: @ocodo: `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` prints "true" or "false" to stdout.  It prints error messages (such as `fatal: not a git repository`) to stderr.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks, I misread the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925062/311660

Answer (score 37):

Or you could do this:

```
inside_git_repo="$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)"

if [ "$inside_git_repo" ]; then
  echo "inside git repo"
else
  echo "not in git repo"
fi
```

Comment: I like this one because it works from a sub directory too

Comment: [No redundant operations and works in `-e` mode: `[ "$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)" == "true" ]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180270/check-if-current-directory-is-a-git-repository/53367550#53367550)

Answer (score 21):

Based on [@Alex Cory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180270/check-if-current-directory-is-a-git-repository/38088814#38088814):

```
[ "$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)" = "true" ]
```

doesn't contain any redundant operations and works in `-e` mode.

- [As @go2null noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180270/check-if-current-directory-is-a-git-repository/53367550#comment93942034_53367550), this will not work in a bare repo. If you want to work with a bare repo for whatever reason, you can just check for `git rev-parse` succeeding, ignoring its output.

  - I don't consider this a drawback because the above line is indended for scripting, and virtually all `git` commands are only valid inside a worktree. So for scripting purposes, you're most likely interested in being not just inside a "git repo" but inside a worktree.

Comment: this fails inside of a bare git repo

Comment: Rather than checking the output, it is better practice to check the return value.  Do not invoke `[` at all. Just do `if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree; then ...` (with redirections as desired.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell checking the exit value doesn't work here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180270/check-if-current-directory-is-a-git-repository/53367550#comment93611897_52938461

Comment: @Ivan_pozdeev Depends on your definition of "work".  In this case, I would say that checking the return value does work, while checking the output does not.  In either case, from the perspective of best practice for writing code in the shell, it is more appropriate to check the return value.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if you read the linked comment, you'd know what I meant by "doesn't work" here.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, except that there is a typo: you need `=`, not `==` (which gives errors like `sh: 1: [: false: unexpected operator`).

Comment: @vinc17 Fixed. In Bash, there's no difference, but outside of Linux, there may be...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks, but note that even under Linux, not all users use bash (the `==` is also invalid in zsh).

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if there is a publicly accessible/documented way to do this (there are some internal git functions which you can use/abuse in the git source itself)

You could do something like;

```
if ! git ls-files >& /dev/null; then
  echo "not in git"
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

This answer provides a sample POSIX shell function and a usage example to complement @jabbie's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2180367/3366962).

```
is_inside_git_repo() {
    git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

`git` returns errorlevel `0` if it is inside a git repository, else it returns errorlevel `128`.  (It also returns `true` or `false` if it is inside a git repository.)

Usage example

```
for repo in *; do
    # skip files
    [ -d "$repo" ] || continue
    # run commands in subshell so each loop starts in the current dir
    (
        cd "$repo"
        # skip plain directories
        is_inside_git_repo || continue
        printf '== %s ==\n' "$repo"
        git remote update --prune 'origin' # example command
        # other commands here
    )
done
```

Comment: Not sufficient. Inside `.git`, it will succeed but print `false`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: If `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` returns `true` or `false` then it *is* inside a git repo, and that is what the function returns.  that is, the function is *correct*

Comment: to expand, see the description in the answer, the value returned from git is ignored, the errorlevel is what is used.

Answer (score 8):

Why not using exit codes? If a git repository exists in the current directory, then `git branch` and `git tag` commands return exit code of 0 (even if there are no tags or branches); otherwise, a non-zero exit code will be returned. This way, you can determine if a git repository exist or not. Simply, you can run:

```bash
git tag > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Advantage**: Portable. It works for both bare and non-bare repositories, and in sh, zsh and bash.

#### Explanation

1. `git tag`: Getting tags of the repository to determine if exists or not.
2. `> /dev/null 2>&1`: Preventing from printing anything, including normal and error outputs.

#### TLDR (<sup>R</sup><sub>e</sub><sup>a</sup><sub>l</sub><sup>l</sup><sub>y</sub><sup>?</sup><sub>!</sub>): `check-git-repo`

As an example, you can create a file named `check-git-repo` with the following contents, make it executable and run it:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if git tag > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Repository exists!";
else
    echo "No repository here.";
fi
```

Comment: The `&& [ $? -eq 0 ]` is redundant, especially if you're already in an `if`.

Comment: does `git tag` work even when there are no tags?

Comment: @jave.web, yes. Thanks for mentioning, added as a side-note.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to check for the command's exit code.

```
git rev-parse 2> /dev/null; [ $? == 0 ] && echo 1
```

This will print 1 if you're in a git repository folder.

Comment: Note that this will have rc 0 even if you're inside the `.git` directory -- which you may or may not want.

Comment: Git's written sanely so you can just close files you don't want, `git rev-parse 2>&-`.

Comment: `[ $? == 0 ]` is redundant here; that's the implied test that `&&` already does.  The above command is equivalent to `git rev-parse 2>/dev/null && echo 1`.

Comment: `[ $? == 0 ]` is not exactly redundant.  If you are using a version of `[` that supports `==`, then it is exactly equivalent to `git rev-parse 2> /dev/null && echo 1`.  But if you are using a version of `[` that does not recognize `==`, then this version is an error.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. You still get the errors but they're easy enough to suppress. it also works from within subfolders!

```sh
git status >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo Hello World!
```

You can put this in an if then statement if you need to conditionally do more.

Comment: Good enough for many cases perhaps, but it fails on a bare git repo.

Comment: `git status` can be very slow on a big/old repo. I wouldn't use it for this purpose.

Comment: @henrebotha I totally agree and I am still doing it, because I would need the output for processing anyways: `git_status="$(git status --porcelain --branch 2> /dev/null)"; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo something with $git_status; fi`

Answer (score 3):

# check if git repo

```
if [ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree) = true ]; then
    echo "yes, is a git repo"
    git pull
else
    echo "no, is not a git repo"
    git clone url --depth 1
fi
```

Comment: This is not best practice.  If run outside of a working directory, you'll get "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" written on stderr, and "no, is not a git repo" on stdout.  There's no need to invoke `[` here at all.  Just do: `if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then ....`

Comment: In my case, I'm comfortable with this, and I want to track this glitch in my logs. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This questions is really old, and there are some nice answers.
Yet there is missing one thing: The solution how it is handled by git itself inside it's `git-prompt.sh` with `__git_ps ()`.
Here is the snippet taken from there:

```bash
    # [...]
    local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
    repo_info="$(git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir \
        --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree \
        --short HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
    rev_parse_exit_code="$?"

    if [ -z "$repo_info" ]; then
        return $exit
    fi

    local short_sha=""
    if [ "$rev_parse_exit_code" = "0" ]; then
        short_sha="${repo_info##*$'\n'}"
        repo_info="${repo_info%$'\n'*}"
    fi
    # [...]
```

This is pretty nice, as it seems to handle all the mentioned issues to the other answers given here. Simply by combining the already known parameters in one call of `git rev-parse`.
Maybe this script (`git-prompt.sh` with `__git_ps ()`) wasn't available 13 years ago, when this question was asked, but I thought it could be still interesting for people who want to create their own ps1.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
##Current branch
echo $(git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null && echo '')
echo $(git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null)

##OR
GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple use any of the git commands like **git branch** or on linux machine if u want to search everywhere for **.git file** to know git folder use these command **sudo find / -type d -name ".git**"