# Test if the current directory is inside a Rails project (bash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

Is there an easy way to test if the current directory is inside a rails project? Clearly Rails itself tests this in order to use the rails subcommands (generate, scaffold, etc.), so presumably there's a straight-forward way to test this.

I'm looking for something similar to how you would [test if you're inside a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180270/zsh-check-if-current-directoy-is-git-repo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I was able to dig into the `rails` command itself and based a solution on part of the `railties` gem (`<railties>/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb`):

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pathname'

SCRIPT_RAILS = File.join('script', 'rails')

def self.in_rails_application?
  File.exists?(SCRIPT_RAILS)
end

def self.in_rails_application_subdirectory?(path = Pathname.new(Dir.pwd))
  File.exists?(File.join(path, SCRIPT_RAILS)) || !path.root? && in_rails_application_subdirectory?(path.parent)
end

if in_rails_application? || in_rails_application_subdirectory?
  exit(0)
else
  exit(1)
end
```

Comment: You could also add Rails 2 compatibility by testing for `script/server` as well as `script/rails`.

Answer (score 5):

I know you already have a solution in ruby, but here's one written in bash, which should be a bit faster.

Assuming you're using Bundler:

```
grep 'rails' 'Gemfile' >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "It's a Rails project!"
fi
```

This is what that snippet does:

1. Grep the Gemfile in the current directory for 'rails'. Discard grep's output.
2. If grep exits with exit code 0, you're in a Rails project

`grep 'rails' 'Gemfile'` will return a status code of 2 if a file named 'Gemfile' doesn't exist in the current directory. `grep` will return a status code of 1 if the found a 'Gemfile' but it doesn't contain 'rails'.

For Rails 2 without Bundler this should work:

```
if [ -f script/rails ]; then
  echo "It's a Rails 2 project!"
fi
```

All that does is test if the script/rails file exists.

I hope this helps someone who's hoping to do it bash instead of ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There are no file or directory specific to Rails. so you can't really know if you are or not in a rails directory.

The better solution can be to know if you have rails or railities gem dependencies in your Gemfile.

```
bundle list | grep 'rail'
```