# PHP what does this shell command do?

Tags: php, shell, exec

I found this line in a project:

```
exec('php '.$myPath."/somefile.php bah blha blha --myparam=$param > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &";)
```

What does this line mean?

I know that it runs a `somefile.php` with parameter `myparam`, but that are these parts: `/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &` , `bah blha blha` ?

Comment: `/dev/null` send output to /dev/null; `2>&1` send error output to the same place as output; `< /dev/null` take input from /dev/null; and `bah blha blha` are command line arguments passed to the php script

Comment: It's about redirecting output and input.  
There's a good explanation on AskUbuntu.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the syntax in question is bash syntax. You can start [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) to learn more.

However, here comes a little explanation:

```
> /dev/null
```

means that the output is redirected to /dev/null what means that the output of the program will be thrown away

```
2>&1
```

means that stderr is redirected to stdout. As stdout is *thrown away* errors will be thrown away too.

```
< /dev/null
```

means that /dev/null is piped to stdin of the program - what is actually nothing.

```
&
```

at the end of the line means, that the program should run in background what makes exec  return immediately

Answer (score 1):

/dev/null is a black hole and it seems both the results sent to STDOUT (standard out, usually your screen) and STDERR (standard error) to the black hole. So in summary, it does nothing.