# How to hide output of mongo terminal (Node.Js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, terminal, output

I am working with MongoDB in a Node server.

While my program is running i get a lot of output in the shell, like querys and other information. If i am right that is a lot of work more for the process, so i want to hide all kind of output.

I try runing the comand with the parameter --quiet

```
mongod --quiet
```

So i assume that i miss a configuration in the mongo driver of node.

Technicals:

- MongoDB Version: 3.2.9
- Node Version:v6.4.0

Comment: `--quiet` is to be _less chatty_. To remove everything, what if you say `mongo &>/dev/null`? All the output will go to `/dev/null` and hence not showed.

Comment: @fedorqui amazing, thanks you man, now, can you explain me a little more what its happend?

Comment: Glad that it worked. I added an answer to have space enough to explain it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[mongod documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/) states:

> ```
> --quiet
> ```
>
> Runs the mongod in a quiet mode that attempts to limit the amount of
>   output.
>
> This option suppresses:
>
> - output from database commands
> - replication activity
> - connection accepted events  connection closed events

So still some output emerges from the process. To prevent this and hide ALL the output, both stdout and stderr, you need to say either of these equivalent commands:

```
process &>/dev/null
process >/dev/null 2>&1
```

In your case:

```
mongod &>/dev/null
mongod >/dev/null 2>&1
```

See [What is /dev/null 2>&1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10508843/1983854) for some explanations on how this works.

Comment: How to achieve the same in windows?

Comment: @PranshTiwari : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/is-there-a-dev-null-on-windows