# Redirect output of Linux system() call command to a varriable only

Tags: c++, linux, command, io-redirection

I have to run a system command in a my C++ code:

`int val = system( "pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -c 'state: RUNNING'" );`

The command returns the result to `val` which is desirable, but also `val` or the return of the call( I can't seem to figure out which one ) also gets written to `stdout` and prints on the terminal.

Is there a way to redirect the call to **NOT** write to `stdout` or anywhere but to `val`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the output of the last command to the `/dev/null` does the trick.

The final command looks like this:

```
int val = system( "pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -c 'state: RUNNING' > /dev/null" );
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21#answer-10508859) is a nice post that explains `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash [Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) will help.

> If |& is used, the standard error of command is connected to command2’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1 |.

Thus you can use the command below

`int val = system( "pacmd list-sink-inputs &| grep -c 'state: RUNNING'" );`

or

`int val = system( "pacmd list-sink-inputs 2>&1| grep -c 'state: RUNNING'" );`

Comment: that did no solve the problem, it still gets sent to console

Comment: grep is writing to stderr too, I want it to write to nowhere, bash should just discard the result of grep.

Comment: You can  redirect  stderr to stdout if grep is writing to stderr too.  int val = system( "pacmd list-sink-inputs 2>&1| grep -c 'state: RUNNING' 2>&1" );

Comment: And which language do you use? I think you could misuse  the function system. Like python, we can use  val = subprocess.check_output("pacmd list-sink-inputs 2>&1| grep -c 'state: RUNNING'" )   to set the command result to val. But if we use  val = subprocess.call("pacmd list-sink-inputs 2>&1| grep -c 'state: RUNNING'") , the value of val will nerver get the result of the command we call just the retcode.