# How to combine Unix input + output redirects?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a rsync command that does this:

```
rsync -a path postgres@12.19.232.116:/home/postgres/data/wals < /dev/null
```

I want to also redirect the output of this command to a file (ie > output.log), while preserving < /dev/null. How do I do so?

Comment: `rsync -a postgres@12.19.232.116:/home/postgres/data/wals < /dev/null
 > output.log`

Comment: You may also find this useful: What is /dev/null 2>&1?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21

Comment: @HenleyChiu: Just being curious: What's the purpose to redirect stdin to the bitbucket? In your command, rsync is not reading from stdin anyway.

Comment: it's one of those things where it's has been working well with that for the past 3 years, and I don't want to change it because my job now is to add the new redirect, not change stuff :) Sure, I could refactor it but that's easy to say when u're not the one that wakes up at 2 AM when something unforseen happens :)