# what does this error >/dev/null 2>/dev/null) mean

Tags: cron

I have this error in logs file

```
CRON[3304]: (root) CMD (   /usr/bin/php /home/app/foxorders/scripts/restart_apache.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null)
```

Whats mean please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is /dev/null 2>&1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21)

Comment: @Simon, this Q/A may answer the question, but OP will mess more, AFAIK he/she search for sample, straight answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not a error. It's just information about `cron` job which execute command:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/app/foxorders/scripts/restart_apache.php
```

and redirect `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to `NULL` device