# Laravel Artisan command launched by cron job fails without error message

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel 9 application with some artisan commands to do some background tasks. One of these commands updates a data warehouse (update:dwh). This command runs without problems from the command line, but it **fails after running for ~240 secs, if run by a cron job** (see cron command below). I do not get any error message. The cron log (see below) only shows that the command failed. I also log the artisan commands to a file, but it stays empty (no error message). I suspect that the issue might be caused by the different environments (triggered by command line / cron job) and maybe by the long execution time (240 sec) or relatively high memory usage, but without any error messages, I do not know what to fix. Any ideas about how to get some meaningful error messages about the root cause of this issue? Any other hints on what can cause the command to fail?

[image]

Cron job log file:

```
2023-09-15 07:01:45 Running ['artisan' update:dwh] 
   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  


   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  


   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  


  2023-09-15 07:05:01 Running ['artisan' queue:work --stop-when-empty]  3,276ms DONE
  ⇂ '/usr/local/php82/bin/php-cli' 'artisan' queue:work --stop-when-empty >> 'storage/logs/artilog.txt' 2>&1  

.......... 241,114ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/usr/local/php82/bin/php-cli' 'artisan' update:dwh >> 'storage/logs/artilog.txt' 2>&1  


   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  


   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  


   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  


   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

Comment: How did you run the scheduler? Is it the same from the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: Thanks for the link, maybe it was not clear, but the cron job starts the artisan scheduler and the command without any problems, but the command fails without any error message after ~240 sec. I added my cron entry for your review. Thanks!

Comment: Try removing all the processing logic from your command and just write a line to a log file, does the command run successfully? If it does, reintroduce parts of the code (if you can) until something fails so you know what is causing the problem. Also, does your command need a logged in user to perform its action? Authorisation might be blocking the command from doing what it needs to do.

Comment: Thanks! I tried all this. The command runs without a problem every year, until the database reaches a certain size (it works on yearly data) then I start seeing this problem. Last year I removed some parts of the processing and this made it working again. My feeling is that it reaches some memory or execution time limit, but I do not know, how to really know what the bottleneck is. Any further hints?

Comment: so basically a timeout.

Comment: Can you do this in batches instead? If you are loading/fetching 100s of data from db, I read that you can batch them using chunks (never tried them but it might work for you)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: Though in php.ini side, I guess you can increase the max_execution time only in your cron scrips. something like this at the top of the cron script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171228

Comment: Most probable error for this is `allowed memory exhaust` No error message on cron might be because you added `>> /dev/null 2>&1` in your cron job.

Comment: Just like what this SO answer said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508862

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth Thanks for the hints! My remarks: 1. there is no max_execution_time in php cli, so I do not think the command could time out:   https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time 2: I'm already logging the available memory and the script does not seem to reach it 3: based on my cron job above the output should go to the attached file (cronlog.txt - and not to dev/null) so I do not understand, why I don't see any error messages. 4. I will still try out chunking results, thanks!

Comment: when I say `top of the cron scripts` I meant in the `PHP class` that you created for the cron job/scheduler. Might be below the namespace or inside the `handle()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple exchanges with my hosting company, it turned out that they have a special limitation (not part of the normal php configuration) that does not allow cron tasks to run longer than 2 minutes. I had refactor and split the cron job into multiple smaller cron-jobs and tasks and now all steps run through without any problems.